# is there any way to save the marker information coming from server

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an Api which gives me a marker location to be plotted on the map. my api would download the pins or marker with some extra information.

But wondering how to save the information of those markers so that each marker when plotted on the map should have its on information and then on its click event I want to show its detail in next activity.

Please tell me How can I achieve this ? Should I have to made the Model class as we do for listview and adapter when downloading data from the api and parse it later ?? What should i supposed to do ? What is a best way ? please help me and give me some idea and source code

Comment: This site is not intended for askers to simply be provided with generic source code; please attempt the problem yourself and outline the difficulties you faced, including an example of the portion of your code giving you problems.

Comment: Oh A bundle of thanks @Grade'Eh'Bacon for providing me a huge information

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Comment: @tyczj this is not the case with me , I know how to save the data but specifically for markers I am asking what things do I need to save the data of markers for google maps

Comment: I dont understand what the problem is, a marker has a lat/lng save that info you want with the lat/lng

Comment: @tyczj may be I am not making you understand , let me ask you simple question , I have service which returns too many marker from any part of the world's location , i have to plot them on map , and also when the user click on the marker it should show all of its information whcih I got from the  the api

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just save you location (Latitude & Longitude) whenever you need marker you can plot it at any time using your saved locations.

Comment: i know i can save it , but the point is , suppose I have location of person coming from server api along with his name , age , etc , So I want to save its information and plot the marker only with that user name and when that marker is got clicked other information should be shown into next activity. So what is best way to save it ?

Comment: What you mean whcih format ? I am getting jason information from api and I parse it and uses a direct method (googleMap.addMarker) to plot the marker now on click I have to show the specific information of that marker .